# Getting an error when trying to connect to SMTP server "199.201.221.19"

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient, mailkit

I am using the following code and getting an error when trying to connect to SMTP server. I am not giving any authentication credentials to access that.

```
var client = new SmtpClient()
await client.ConnectAsync("199.201.221.19", 587, false);
client.Send(mail);
```

**Host**:199.201.221.19
**Port**:587
**Error**: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
What is the actual issue and what is the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to an SSL/TLS certificate validation error. It means that your server's SSL certificate does not verify using .NET's standard Root CA certificates.

Even though you have specified `useSsl` as `false` in your ConnectAsync() method call, MailKit will still toggle into TLS-mode if the server supports `STARTTLS`. The `useSsl` parameter is really only useul in telling MailKit whether or not the port requires SSL from the very start (as in ssl-wrapped ports such as 993 for IMAP/S, 995 for POP/S and 465 for SMTP/S).

You have 2 options for fixing this problem:

1. Follow the directions for this error in the FAQ: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#InvalidSslCertificate
2. use a different ConnectAsync method that allows you to specify not to try `STARTTLS`: client.ConnectAsync (host, port, SecureSocketOptions.None);